# Using a timer, how to run a function from another user control when the time elapsed

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a WPF user control called TimerUserControl where contains a timer. And I have another user control where show questions, this one has a NextQuestion function.

The timer has 2 minutes like an interval, and I'd like to invoke the NextQuestion function when it has done. I think I have to use delegates, but I'm not sure.

UPDATE 1:

```
public partial class TimeUserControl : UserControl
{
    public int _totalSeconds;
    public int _secondsRemaining;
    public DispatcherTimer timerSecondsLeft;

    public TimeUserControl()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        timerSecondsLeft = new DispatcherTimer();
        timerSecondsLeft.Tick += new EventHandler(timerSecondsLeft_Tick);
        timerSecondsLeft.Interval = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 1);
    }

    public bool TimesUp
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    public void SetSeconds(int seconds)
    {
        timerSecondsLeft.Stop();

        if (seconds == 0)
        {
            TimeTextBlock.Text = "There's no time! Hurray";
        }
        else
        {
            _totalSeconds = seconds;
            _secondsRemaining = seconds;

            TimeTextBlock.Text = string.Format("It remains {0} seconds. Don't take long!", _totalSeconds);
            timerSecondsLeft.Start();
        }
    }

    public void timerSecondsLeft_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        _secondsRemaining--;

        if (_secondsRemaining <= 0)
        {
            timerSecondsLeft.Stop();

            TimesUp = true;
            TimeTextBlock.Text = "Time's up. Press Enter to next problem.";

            // HERE WILL INVOKE NEXTQUESTION FUNCTION
        }
        else
        {
            TimeTextBlock.Text = string.Format("It remains {0} seconds. Don't take long!", _secondsRemaining);
        }
    }
}
```

Look in the code, the comment is this possible ussing delegates?

Comment: It may be helpful to show some of your code, or at least stripped down versions of the classes you intend to work with.  People are generally more inclined to answer that way.

Comment: Is there any reason that you couldn't just use an event?

Comment: There's no problem, but how can I do that?

Comment: You need to create a custom event inside this class. The event will be fired when the timerSecondsLeft <= 0. You will subscribe to this event inside the parent class(where the TimerUserControl is implemented). Give me a few minutes I'll post an answer that should get you going.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So you need to do a few things. You have to add some code to you're user control.

```
// Declare this outside your usercontrol class
public delegate void TimerExpiredEventHandler(object sender, EventArgs e);
```

This is what needs to be added to your code for the user control.

```
public partial class TimerUserControl : UserControl
{
    public event TimerExpiredEventHandler Expired;

    public void OnExpired(EventArgs e)
    {
        if (Expired != null)
            Expired(this, e);
    }

public void timerSecondsLeft_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    _secondsRemaining--;

    if (_secondsRemaining <= 0)
    {
        timerSecondsLeft.Stop();

        TimesUp = true;
        TimeTextBlock.Text = "Time's up. Press Enter to next problem.";

        // Fire the event here.
        OnExpired(EventArgs.Empty);
    }
    else
    {
        TimeTextBlock.Text = string.Format("It remains {0} seconds. Don't take long!", _secondsRemaining);
    }
}

}
```

Now you need to subscribe to this event inside whatever is calling this usercontrol in the first place.

```
public partial class ParentForm : Form
{
    private void ParentForm_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
         var timer = new TimerUserControl();
         //Subscribe to the expired event that we defined above.
         timer.Expired += new EventArgs(Timer_Expired);
    }

    public void Timer_Expired(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //Handle the timer expiring here. Sounds like you are calling another function, so do that here.
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the TreeHelper to hunt up the tree for a shared Parent and then down the tree for the User Control you want. Something like this pseudo code:

```
this.Timer = new System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherTimer
{
    Interval = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 1)
};
this.Timer.Tick += (s, e) =>
{
    var _Control = s as MyFirstControl;
    var _Other = LogicalTreeHelper.GetChildren(_Control.Parent)
        .Cast<FrameworkElement>().Where(x => x.Name == "FindIt")
        .First<MySecondControl>();
    _Other.DoMethod();
};
```

Best of luck!

Answer (score 0):

i would probably break out the functionality of the timer control here; something like this (note: i am writing this on-the-fly so let me know if it doesn't work as-is, and i will help correct any issues):

```
// a simple delegate to report the amount of time remaining 
// prior to the expiration of the major tick interval; zero
// indicates that this major tick has elapsed.
public delegate void delegateMajorMinorTimerTick
  (
    int TimeRemaining_sec, ref bool CancelTimer
  );

// you could use milliseconds for the interval settings to get
// better granularity, or you could switch to setting the major
// interval instead, however that approach would require a bit 
// more checking to make sure the control has sane settings.
public class MajorMinorTimer
{
  // this sets the interval in seconds between the
  // "minor" ticks used for intermediate processing
  // these are the "inner" intervals of the timer
  private int myMinorTickInterval_sec;
  public int MinorTickInterval_sec
  {
    get { return myMinorTickInterval_sec; }  
  } 

  // this sets the number of minor ticks between the
  // expiration of the major interval of the timer.
  // the "outer" interval of the timer
  private int myMinorTicksPerMajorTick;
  public int MinorTicksPerMajorTick
  {
    get { return myMinorTicksPerMajorTick; }
  }

  public MajorMinorTimer
    (
      int parMinorTickInterval_sec,
      int parMinorTicksPerMajorTick
    )
  {
    MinorTickInterval_sec = parMinorTickInterval_sec;
    MinorTicksPerMajorTick = parMinorTicksPerMajorTick;
  } 

  private DispatcherTimer myBackingTimer; 

  private int myMinorTickCount;
  public void Start()
  {
    // reset the minor tick count and start the dispatcher
    // timer with some reasonable defaults.
    myMinorTickCount = 0;
    myBackingTimer = 
      new DispatcherTimer
        (
          TimeSpan.FromSeconds(MinorTickInterval_sec),
          DispatcherPriority.Normal,
          new EventHandler(myBackingTimer_Tick),
          Dispatcher.CurrentDispatcher
        );

    myBackingTimer.Start();
  }

  public event delegateMajorMinorTimerTick onTick;
  private bool FireMajorMinorTimerTick(int TimeRemaining_sec)
  {
    // allows the timer sink to cancel the timer after this
    // call; just as an idea, also could be handled with a
    // call to Stop() during the event, but this 
    // simplifies handling a bit (at least to my tastes)
    bool CancelTimer = false; 

    if (onTick != null)
      onTick(TimeRemaining_sec, ref CancelTimer);

    return CancelTimer;
  }

  private void myBackingTimer_Tick(object Sender, EventArgs e)
  {
    // since we are using a DispatchTimer with settings that should
    // do not suggest the possibility of synchronization issues,
    // we do not provide further thread safety.  this could be
    // accomplished in the future if necessary with a lock() call or
    // Mutex, among other methods.
    ++myMinorTickCount;

    int TicksRemaining = myMinorTickCount - MinorTicksPerMajorTick;
    bool Cancel = 
      FireMajorMinorTimerTick(TicksRemaining * MinorTickInterval_sec);

    if (TicksRemaining == 0)
      myMinorTickCount = 0;

    if (Cancel)
      Stop();
  }

  public void Stop()
  {
     myBackingTimer.Stop();
  }
}
```

then, assuming, say, a Quiz control, the timer is used like so:

```
public void QuestionTimerSetup()
{
  // sets up a timer to fire a minor tick every second
  // with a major interval of 5 seconds
  MajorMinorTimer timerQuestion = new MajorMinorTimer(1, 5); 

  timerQuestion.onTick += 
    new delegateMajorMinorTimerTick(QuestionControl_QuestionTimerTick);
}

// ...

public void QuestionControl_OnTick(int TimeRemaining_sec, ref bool CancelTimer)
{
  if (TimeRemaining_sec > 0)
  {
    tblockQuizStatus.Text = 
      string.Format("There are {0} seconds remaining.", TimeRemaining_sec);
  }
  else
  {
    // just for an example
    if (NoMoreQuestions)
    {
       CancelTimer = true;
       HandleEndOfQuiz();
       tblockQuizStatus.Text =
         "Time's up!  The quiz is complete!";
    }
    else
    {
       tblockQuizStatus.Text = 
         "Time's up!  Press Enter to continue to the next problem.";
    }
  }
}
```

another option (rather than, or in addition to, events) in implementing this might be to add an `Action` taking the time remaining in the major interval for the minor interval action, an `Action` for the major interval action, and a `Func<bool>` that checks the stop condition, allowing the user to perform the desired actions in that way. like this:

```
public class MajorMinorTimer
{
  public MajorMinorTimer
    (
      int parMinorTimerInterval_sec,
      int parMinorTicksPerMajorTick,
      Action<int> parMinorTickAction,
      Action parMajorTickAction,
      Func<bool> parShouldStopFunc
     )
  {
    myMinorTimerInterval_sec = parMinorTimerInterval_sec;
    myMinorTicksPerMajorTick = parMinorTicksPerMajorTick;
    myMinorTickAction = parMinorTickAction;
    myMajorTickAction = parMajorTickAction;
    myShouldStopFunc = parShouldStopFunc;
  }

  private Action<int> myMinorTickAction;
  private Action myMajorTickAction;
  private Func<bool> myShouldStopFunc;

  private void myBackingTimer_OnTick()
  {
    ++myMinorTickCount;

    int TicksRemaining = myMinorTickCount - MinorTicksPerMajorTick;

    if (TicksRemaining == 0)
      myMajorTickAction();
    else
      myMinorTickAction(TicksRemaining * MinorTickInterval_sec);

    bool Cancel = myShouldStopFunc();

    if (TicksRemaining == 0)
      myMinorTickCount = 0;

    if (Cancel)
      Stop();
  }
}
```

and then in the quiz code instead of hooking up the event do something like:

```
public void QuestionTimerSetup()
{
  MajorMinorTimer timerQuestion = 
    new MajorMinorTimer
      (
        1,
        5,
        // major interval action
        (SecsRemaining) => 
          {
            tblockQuizStatus.Text = 
              string.Format
                (
                  "There are {0} seconds remaining.", SecsRemaining
                );
          },
        // minor interval action
        () => 
          {
            if (NoMoreQuestions)
            {
              tblockQuizStatus.Text = 
                "Time's up!  This completes the quiz!";
              HandleEndOfQuiz();
            }
            else
            {
              tblockQuizStatus.Text = 
                "Time's up!  Press Enter to continue to next question.";
            }
          },
        // timer cancel check function
        () => 
          IsEndOfQuizHandled()
      ); 
}
```

Comment: so i know that glosses over some of the difficulty of the actual quiz control/form/whatever, but hopefully that gives you some ideas.  let me know if there are any issues with the code or if you have any other questions i'll do my best to help! ♡

Comment: also: if you are implementing this from scratch, i would recommend decoupling the UI update from the question timer altogether. i would prefer to have two stock timers here (or if you find the `Action` way preferable, a simple `TimerUserControl` that just mirrors the backing timer), one which fires to update the UI, and one which fires when the time is up for a question. in this example it wouldn't make much difference, but if things get more complex later (e.g., if you want to update multiple UI elements; or, to update the UI more quickly) then it can simplify your life down the road. ♡